# How to add an ABAPDoc for a method that is an enhancement of a standard class?

Tags: abap

I have extended a class by one method, using the Enhancement Framework.

[image: Enhanced class]

Now, my problem is that I want to add [ABAPDoc](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abendoccomment.htm) to it but cannot find any way to do it!

The code in the Enhancement Include section seems to be editable in no way.

[image: Enhancement Include]

Is there any way to do it at all? I tried also from ADT in Eclipse but this calls the SAP GUI anyway.

Comment: do you wanna add doc to enhancement itself or to method of implementing class? you are enhancing somewhat like BOL or WDA application in CRM?

Comment: @Suncatcher Hi! I just want to add ABAPDoc exactly in the same way I would do it for an ordinary method in my own custom class. I am using [the part of Enhancement Framework for enhancing classes/interfaces](https://help.sap.com/viewer/12a713d06c531014bb73ec422d9d0cca/7.0.37/en-US/584fb541d3d52d31e10000000a155106.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do is indeed impossible.

The enhancement include is a technical object and it cannot be edited from the tab you highlighted, it is auto-generated as you changing pre- and post-methods.

What this tab shows is not an include itself, but the placement of the enh. include within the parent object

[image]

If you want to change the method comment from enhancement, you should go to Technical details tab and click on changed object, or just go to the class in SE24 and press to pre/post exit button, and you will end up in the same include:

[image]

You can write the ABAPDoc-syntaxed comment, but for me it didn't work, and Eclipse didn't recognized my comment written in SAPGui, maybe you will be luckier.

ABAPDoc team [describes](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/04/29/abap-doc/#comment-243354) this piece in a fuzzy manner, it may be an expected behavior:

> **This ABAPDoc is only available to ADT and not SE80? I can not use it in SAP GUI development?**

> You can also write it in the source code and you will get also warnings when you execute a check, but there is no dedicated tools support like source code element information or quick assist (Ctrl+1)

To your principal question, ABAPDoc is a two-way road when viewing: the ABAPDocs can be viewed both from the Eclipse and SE80, and they are automatically showed in SE80 description fields ([but only](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/abap-dev-create-abapdoc.html#e87b2705-fefc-4032-aece-418f7483926b) if they are declared **synchronized**).

But it seems to be a one-way road for edit: they can be created only in ADT Eclipse to be fully compatible. If the object cannot be opened in Eclipse natively like your enhancement you are out of the luck.

I put *seems* because I am not 100% sure. Maybe on later systems it was fixed, but on my 750 they are not recognized by Eclipse for enhanced methods.

The only reliable way of "editing" via SE80 is writing the comments to descriptions and then importing these SE80 descriptions into ABAPDoc in Eclipse

[image]

which is ridiculous in context of your question, so there is no way for you.